# Delete rows in table that are sum of other rows per group

Tags: sql, sql-server

Group rows by `T`, and in each group find the row that is the largest or smallest (if values are negative) sum of other rows from that group, and delete that row (one for each group), if group does not have enough elements to find sum or enough but none of the rows indicates sum of others nothing happens

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
    T   varchar(10),
    V   int
);
INSERT INTO Test
    VALUES ('A',  4), 
           ('B', -5), 
           ('C',  5), 
           ('A',  2), 
           ('B', -1), 
           ('C', 10), 
           ('A',  2), 
           ('B', -4), 
           ('C',  5), 
           ('D',  0);
```

expected result:

```
A    2
A    2
B   -1
B   -4
C    5
C    5
D    0
```

Comment: Please post the expected result.

Comment: updated question with result

Comment: Why is `D` retained?

Comment: it's much more difficult due to you not having a key column. It makes finding "other rows in the group" unnecessarily difficult

Comment: because D is not sum of anything, it's single in the group of Ds, for 2 Ds would be the same, minimum 3 values in group are needed so that one of those values can be sum of others

Comment: @bmsqldev, no, it's -5

Comment: -5 is smaller than -4 or -1 :)

Comment: sorry. but -1 is the largest negative value for 'B' is it? as per question largest or  smallest negative value should be deleted. what is the criteria to choose largest or smallest?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, OP wants to delete the smallest value if the values are negative. Which leads to the question, what if there are combinations of positive and negative values in a single group.

Comment: if the largest or smallest value is not sum of other rows, does it gets deleted ?

Comment: if group is smaller than 3 rows it's ignored

Comment: @PrzemysławBanaszek, what if the group has both positive and negative values?

Comment: if u cannot find sum in the group ignore it

Comment: What do you mean by sum of others? The sum of `T`s are: `A = 8`, `B = -10`, `C = 20`, `D = 0`? How do you know which rows are to be deleted?

Comment: A has values 2,2,4 so 4 is the sum of 2+2 therefore 4 which is the largest of all values from A has been removed

Comment: So for a group with the values 1,1,2,4, which would you remove? 1+1=2 and 1+1+2=4. Remove only the ones, because they are the smallest values adding up to another exiting value? Or remove the ones and the two for some reason? And what about 1,1,5,5,8,10? Remove 1+1+8 or 5+5? The ones are lower than the fives, but the eight is higher.

Comment: 1+1+2=4 - 4 would be removed and from 1,1,5,5,8,10 nothing would be removed because there is no element that is the sum of all other elements from the group

Comment: Ah, okay, I misread. The result shown is not the rows to be deleted, but those that remain. My bad. And the value must the sum af all other elements, so 10 is not to be removed hence. Okay.

Comment: ok people thank you for help!, for the moment I do not know which solution is the best one (simplest) I'll pick one soon for the answer, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments, the requirements seem strange.  The below code assumes that the summing is already pre-populated and merely removes the largest/smallest as long as the highest value is not 0.

```
if object_id('tempdb..#test') is not null
drop table #test

CREATE TABLE #Test (
    T   varchar(10),
    V   int
);
INSERT INTO #Test
    VALUES ('A', 4), ('B', -5), ('C', 5), ('A', 2), ('B', -1), ('C', 10), ('A', 2), ('B', -4), ('C', 5), ('D', 0);


if object_id('tempdb..#test2') is not null
drop table #test2

SELECT
T,
V,
ABS(V) as absV
INTO #TEST2
FROM #TEST
SELECT * FROM #TEST2

if object_id('tempdb..#max') is not null
drop table #max

SELECT
T,
MAX(absV) AS MaxAbsV
INTO #Max
FROM #TEST2
GROUP BY T
HAVING MAX(AbsV) != 0



DELETE #TEST2
FROM #TEST2
INNER JOIN #MAX ON #TEST2.T = #MAX.T AND #TEST2.absV = #Max.MaxAbsV

SELECT * FROM #TEST2
ORDER BY T ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
; with cte as
(
    select  T, V, 
        R = row_number() over (partition by T order by ABS(V) desc),
        C = count(*) over (partition by T)
    from    Test 
)
delete  c
from    cte c
    inner join
    (
        select  T, S = sum(V)
        from    cte
        where   R   <> 1
        group by T
    ) s on  c.T = s.T
where   c.C >= 3 
and c.R = 1
and c.V = s.S
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ABS and NOT Exists

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE  (
    T   varchar(10),
    V   int
);
INSERT INTO @Test
    VALUES ('A', 4), ('B', -5), ('C', 5), ('A', 2), ('B', -1), ('C', 10), ('A', 2), ('B', -4), ('C', 5), ('D', 0);

    ;WITH CTE as (
    select T,max(ABS(v ))v from @Test
    WHERE V <> 0
    GROUP BY T )

SELECT T,V FROM @Test T where NOT exists (Select 1 FROM cte WHERE T = T.T AND v = ABS(T.V) )
ORDER BY T.T
```

Comment: no I'm getting the same result please can you once execute in your machine

Comment: [**DEMO**](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/488580). `A,5` here should not be deleted as it's not equal to the sum of `2 + 2`.

Answer (score 1):

Determine first if the rows are positive or negative by checking if `SUM(V)` is positive. And then determine if the smallest or largest value is equal to the `SUM` of the other rows, by subtracting from `SUM(V)` the `MIN(V)` if negative or `MAX(V)` if positive:

```
DELETE t 
FROM Test t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        T, 
        SUM(V) - CASE WHEN SUM(V) >= 0 THEN MAX(V) ELSE MIN(V) END AS ToDelete
    FROM Test 
    GROUP BY T
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
) a
    ON a.T = t.T
    AND a.ToDelete = t.V
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/488579)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below query to get the required output :-

```
select * into #t1 from test

select * from
(
select TT.T as T,TT.V as V
from  test TT
JOIN
(select T,max(abs(V)) as V from #t1 
group by T) P
on TT.T=P.T
where abs(TT.V) <> P.V

UNION ALL


select A.T as T,A.V as V from test A
JOIN(
select T,count(T) as Tcount from test
group by T
having count(T)=1) B on A.T=B.T
) X order by T

drop table #t1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a value per group that is the sum of all the group's other values. E.g. 4 of (2,2,4) or -5 of (-5,-4,-1).

This is usually only one record per group. But it can be multiple times the same number. Here are examples for ties: (0,0) or (-2,2,4,4), or (-2,-2,4,4,4) or (-10,3,3,3,3,4).

As you see, you are looking in any way for values that equal half of the group's total sum. (Of course. We are looking for n+n, where one n is in one record and the other n is the sum of all the other records.)

The only special case is when there is only one value in the group which is zero. That we don't want to delete of course.

Here is an update statement that cannot deal with ties, but would delete all maximum values instead of just one:

```
delete from test
where 2 * v =
(
  select case when count(*) = 1 then null else sum(v) end
  from test fullgroup
  where fullgroup.t = test.t
);
```

In order to deal with ties you would need artificial row numbers, so as to delete only one record of all candidates.

```
with candidates as
(
  select t, v, row_number() over (partition by t order by t) as rn
  from
  (
    select 
      t, v, 
      sum(v) over (partition by t) as sumv, 
      count(*) over (partition by t) as cnt
    from test
  ) comparables
  where sumv = 2 * v and cnt > 1
) 
delete
from candidates
where rn = 1;
```

SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6d97e/1

Answer (score 0):

See if below query helps:

```
DELETE [Audit].[dbo].[Test] FROM [Audit].[dbo].[Test] as AA
INNER JOIN (select T, 
      CASE 
          WHEN MAX(V) < 0 THEN MIN(V) 
          WHEN MIN(V) > 0 THEN MAX(V) ELSE MAX(V)
      END as MAX_V,
      CASE 
          WHEN SUM(V) > 0 THEN  SUM(V) - MAX(V)
          WHEN SUM(V) < 0 THEN  SUM(V) - MIN(V) ELSE SUM(V)
      END as SUM_V_REST
      from [Audit].[dbo].[Test] 
      Group by T 
      Having Count(V) > 1) as BB ON AA.T = BB.T and AA.V = BB.MAX_V
```